# If textarea contains "eat" then output a line of text saying "something"

Tags: javascript, string, if-statement, textarea, contains

I am currently writing a text adventure (web-based) and I need a textarea which the player can write in, and if this textarea contains a certain word (e.g. eat) the next line of code should appear.
Enter has the function of submitting the message. -> If the submitted message is "eat" output "something".

Comment: Can you post your code so far along with what you've already tried?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
$('#uinput').on('keyup', function() {
  if ($(this).val().trim() === "eat") {
    console.log("input value is eat");
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="uinput"></textarea>
```

Comment: @JakobLbk was this helpful?